# Dominar 400 start button hitting the gas tank

Tags: motorcycle, bajaj

I purchased a new Bajaj Dominar 400. I am transitioning from scooter to motorcycle so I don't really know anything about the motorcycle.

The first issue I am encountering is when fully steering to the right the start button is hitting the gas tank ! which is problematic as you can imagine.

Could that be normal behavior ? Like in the case wherein a motorcycle we're not supposed to fully steer?

Could unscrewing the handlebar and adjusting its position solve the problem? (I would hate to start fiddling with a brand new bike)

Many thanks

[image]

VIDEO
[video about start issue](https://mega.nz/#!vNFCDQTC!KxP4yNeauTAJNyNhUB8ld4YVSeQ3STBjtZZHO1PKgLI)

Comment: I would look into the specific bike and see how it is supposed to be from the factory. Obviously, if its not like that from the factory, then you can probably easily move it into proper position like you said. If it is like that from factory, I would still look into moving it, maybe see if anyone else has tried it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a design flaw. You better check with a brand new one to make sure. But I can imagine this causing some issues. You almost never full lock while driving but you might full lock while getting out of a parking spot. Your bike also might full lock if you fell on the left side. Obvious issue here is that if you keep your starter button pressed, you will drain the battery. Messing with handlebars, especially moving them left or right is not a good idea. Can you send a picture of the handlebar assembly and we can try to find a good way around it?

Comment: hey man, thanks for the answer! i added a picture to the original post, please check it and let me know what do you think. thanks again !

Comment: i also posted a link to a video demonstrating the issue

Comment: Here is what I suggest. It is not smart to change the angle drasticly. Also it is not smart to mess with the centering of the handlebar. One thing you can try is bar risers. If you are not particularly short it should not effect the handling. But you may need new clutch or throttle cables. Or even a new break line depending on the length of those cables. But apart from that I have no smart alternative.

Comment: so i took it to the dealer and they fixed it, there was an issue with the handlebar position. thanks for the help

Comment: for future reference can you please explain more? How did they fix it? Was the handle bar out of alignment as stock? If so that is some poor build quality right there.

Comment: so what he did is, he unscrewed the 4 star screws in the middle of the handlebar and he raised it till it got in the correct position then he fastened them again. i don't think all dominars come like this. its probably a mistake from the dealer

Answer (score 0):

It may be normal for that motorcycle, but it's not "normal".  By all means, let the dealer look at it.

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer, i shared a picture and if i cant solve it i will probably take it to the dealer.